# php mysql query multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering if it was possible take data from one table to search  another table and output that data. example take the player's alliance_id and search that alliances tap for the alliance_id and take the alliance name and output the name

**Current query**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM players alliances WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 echo "<table>
   <tr>
 <th>id</th>
 <th>race_id</th>
 <th>alliance_id</th>
 <th>alliance_role_id</th>
 <th>name</th>
  <th>alliance_name</th>
 </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['race_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['alliance_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['alliance_role_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['alliance_name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: yes, it's possible. read up up about SQL [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s.

Comment: @MarcB always seems to be 2 seconds faster than I am. FML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT players.*, alliances.*
FROM players
LEFT JOIN alliances ON players.alliance_id = alliances.id
WHERE players.id = ?
```

**MySQL doc:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html